# rcharts and connectNulls

Tags: r, rcharts

I cant seem to get connectNulls in rcharts to work properly.  The code below should result in the green line connecting april and Junes data.  Instead it simply ignores the null, and acts as if there are only 11 data points.

```
h <- Highcharts$new()
h$xAxis(categories = c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                       'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'))
h$yAxis(list(list(title = list(text = 'Rainfall'))
             , list(title = list(text = 'Temperature'), opposite = TRUE)
             , list(title = list(text = 'Sea Pressure'), opposite = TRUE))
)
h$series(name = 'Rainfall', type = 'column', color = '#4572A7',
         data = c(49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4)
         )
h$series(name = 'Temperature', type = 'spline', color = '#89A54E',
         data = c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, NULL, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6),
         yAxis = 1,  
         connectNulls = TRUE
         )
h$series(name = 'Sea-Level Pressure', type = 'spline', color = '#AA4643',
         data = c(1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7),
         #xAxis = 1,
         yAxis = 2,
         connectNulls = TRUE)
h
```

This is the graph that is produced:
[image: connectNulls not working]

Can someone tell me how to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is really a R thing. Try:

```
length(c(1, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL))
```

Is not 5 but 2. So to force consider that element try consider `list` instead `c`:

```
data = list(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, NULL, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6)
```

Hope it helps.

PS: Just want to invite you to try [highcharter](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/)!